# @RequestBody not binding to a Class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http-post

The following JSON string is being received by the method in my @RestController but not binding to my class:`json = {
  "rsnumberRows": {
    "lnumberRows": 23,
    "tprocessCode": "w",
    "lanomIdx": 123
  },
  "rsdoorInfo": {
    "lnumOfDoors": 5,
    "tdoorNum": {
      "0": "701",
      "1": "702",
      "2": "703",
      "3": "704",
      "4": "705"
    },
    "tdoorUnavailStartDate": {
      "0": "18-JUN-2015 15:51:00",
      "1": "19-JUN-2015 15:51:00",
      "2": "18-JUN-2015 15:51:00",
      "3": "13-JUN-2015 15:51:00",
      "4": "18-JUN-2015 15:51:00"
    },
    "wtrailerMoveRequiredInd": {
      "0": 1,
      "1": 1,
      "2": 0,
      "3": 1,
      "4": 0
    },
    "tdoorUnavailEndDate": {
      "0": "17-JUN-2015 15:51:00",
      "1": "17-JUN-2015 15:51:00",
      "2": "17-JUN-2015 15:51:00",
      "3": "17-JUN-2015 15:51:00",
      "4": "17-JUN-2015 15:51:00"
    }
  }
}`

Controller: `@RequestMapping(path="/SchdDoorMaintenance", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public SchdUpdDoorInfResponse updateDoor(@RequestBody SchdUpdDoorInfJS rSchdUpdDoorInf)
        {
            return schdDoorMaintenanceService.schdUpdDoorInf(rSchdUpdDoorInf);

        }`

The classes receiving the Json data are:

```
public class SchdUpdDoorInfJS {

public SCHDSNumberRowsJS rsNumberRows;
public SCHDSDoorInfoJS rsDoorInfo;
public SCHDSNumberRowsJS getRsNumberRows() {
    return rsNumberRows;
}
public void setRsNumberRows(SCHDSNumberRowsJS rsNumberRows) {
    this.rsNumberRows = rsNumberRows;
}
public SCHDSDoorInfoJS getRsDoorInfo() {
    return rsDoorInfo;
}
public void setRsDoorInfo(SCHDSDoorInfoJS rsDoorInfo) {
    this.rsDoorInfo = rsDoorInfo;
}
```

}

```
public class SCHDSDoorInfoJS  implements Serializable{

public int lNumOfDoors;
public List<String> tDoorNum;
public List<String> tDoorUnavailStartDate;
public List<String> tDoorUnavailEndDate;
public List<Integer> wTrailerMoveRequiredInd;

public int getlNumOfDoors() {
    return lNumOfDoors;
}
public void setlNumOfDoors(int lNumOfDoors) {
    this.lNumOfDoors = lNumOfDoors;
}
public List<String> gettDoorNum() {
    return tDoorNum;
}
public void settDoorNum(List<String> tDoorNum) {
    this.tDoorNum = tDoorNum;
}
public List<String> gettDoorUnavailStartDate() {
    return tDoorUnavailStartDate;
}
public void settDoorUnavailStartDate(List<String> tDoorUnavailStartDate) {
    this.tDoorUnavailStartDate = tDoorUnavailStartDate;
}
public List<String> gettDoorUnavailEndDate() {
    return tDoorUnavailEndDate;
}
public void settDoorUnavailEndDate(List<String> tDoorUnavailEndDate) {
    this.tDoorUnavailEndDate = tDoorUnavailEndDate;
}
public List<Integer> getwTrailerMoveRequiredInd() {
    return wTrailerMoveRequiredInd;
}
public void setwTrailerMoveRequiredInd(List<Integer> wTrailerMoveRequiredInd) {
    this.wTrailerMoveRequiredInd = wTrailerMoveRequiredInd;
}
```

}
and

```
public class SCHDSNumberRowsJS  implements Serializable{

public Integer lNumberRows;
public Integer lAnomIdx;
public String tProcessCode;
public Integer getlNumberRows() {
    return lNumberRows;
}
public void setlNumberRows(Integer lNumberRows) {
    this.lNumberRows = lNumberRows;
}
public Integer getlAnomIdx() {
    return lAnomIdx;
}
public void setlAnomIdx(Integer lAnomIdx) {
    this.lAnomIdx = lAnomIdx;
}
public String gettProcessCode() {
    return tProcessCode;
}
public void settProcessCode(String tProcessCode) {
    this.tProcessCode = tProcessCode;
}
```

}
I do receive the Json string in the request body, however, for some reason the values are not binding to the classes. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the properties are defined as objects in json and lists in java `tdoorNum`, `tdoorUnavailStartDate`, `wtrailerMoveRequiredInd`, and `tdoorUnavailEndDate`.

In json define your lists with `[` and `]` like this:

```
"tdoorNum": [
  "701",
  "702",
  "703",
  "704",
  "705"
]
```

Comment: Another way: you can just write a test or simple main method. Create `SchdUpdDoorInfJS` object with required fields values in java and convert to the json string, after that just simple compare result.